# invisible JFrame from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have 2 classes,one of them extends from JPanel and another one extends from JFrame
now I add class which extends from JPanel,to other class and I wanna to setVisible of JFrame false from JPanel class,how should I do it?

```
public class test extends JPanel{
...
}

public class test2 extends JFrame{
   test t;
   public test2(){
   t = new test();
   }
}
```

I wanna to invisble test2 from test,how should I do it???

Comment: where is the main method? Are you creating the instance of JFrame class from the JPanel class?

Comment: I found the way,
set test2 obj into test method,then inivisble it

Comment: Classnames usually start with a capital: Test, Test2.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to past a refrence of your `JFrame` to the `JPanel` so that it can call `setVisible(false);`.

Although this sounds like a poor design because having each class reference each other is tight coupling and is discouraged. I would suggest having a third "Controller" type class that receives requests from both items and makes changes to the GUI.

Comment: You don't need to pass a reference of the frame to the panel. You can use SwingUtilities to get the Window the panel was added to.